# Unable to Connect to Jconsole - cassandra k8 cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax, jmx, jconsole, cass-operator

cassandra-env.sh

> JMX_PORT=7199
>
> if [ "$LOCAL_JMX" = "yes" ]; then   JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS
> -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=$JMX_PORT"   JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false" else   JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.remote.port=$JMX_PORT"
> JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
> JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
> #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true"   #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.need.client.auth=true"   #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.protocols="
> #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl.enabled.cipher.suites="
> #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/path/to/keystore"   #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword="   #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/truststore"   #JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=" fi

Also

1. set $JMX_PORT to no as environment variable
2. JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=x.x.x.x" (hostname was set to nodeport ip)

I am trying to connect to jconsole remote port using nodeportIp:port.
Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

By design, Cassandra pods are not accessible via JMX outside the Kubernetes cluster. For this reason, there is a management API installed with the Cassandra containers as a sidecar service layer which is used for administrative tasks such as stopping/starting nodes, health checks and running `nodetool` commands.

For details on the Management API for Apache Cassandra, see https://github.com/k8ssandra/management-api-for-apache-cassandra.

You won't be able to directly configure `cassandra-env.sh` because the cass-operator will override it. For details on [K8ssandra.io](https://dtsx.io/3znMa05) security and JMX configuration, see https://docs.k8ssandra.io/tasks/secure/. Cheers!